# Build a new dictionary with concatenated duplicated keys based on values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

How to concatenate and remove duplicates in dictionary like this:

```
Item1: Key=1, Value=test1  
Item2: Key=2, Value=test2  
Item3: Key=3, Value=test1  
Item4: Key=4, Value=test3  
Item5: Key=5, Value=test4
```

To build a new Dictionary like this:

```
Item1: Key=1-3, Value=test1  
Item2: Key=2, Value=test2  

Item4: Key=4, Value=test3  
Item5: Key=5, Value=test4
```

I managed to get the duplicates using this: `myDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);`
But I can't figure the right way to build a new Dictionary from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for taking all the duplicate items into a new dictionary with a shared key:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1", "test1"},
    {"2", "test2"},
    {"3", "test1"}
};

var groupedKeyMap = dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                        .ToDictionary(x => string.Join("-", x.Select(y => y.Key)),
                                      x => x.Key);
```

If you need both duplicate and non duplicate key value pairs, remove the `Where` clause:

```
var groupedKeyMap = dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                        .ToDictionary(x => string.Join("-", x.Select(y => y.Key)),
                                      x => x.Key);
```

Comment: @BobVale Works both ways, but edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes this did it, but the result Dictionary doesn't contain the items which has no duplicates, I need these to keep there, any idea how to do that?